# Createsuperuser: How to show choices of field?

Tags: django

When I use terminal's command `createsuperuser` I see the request to input such info as:

Email address,
Accout type,
Username,
Password,
Password (again).

How is it possible to change the string `Accout type` to something like `Accout type (Options: 1 - organization, 2 - personal)`?

I have the next custom user model (shortened version):

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    USER_ACCOUNT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, _('organization')),
        (2, _('personal')),
    )

    user_account_type = models.IntegerField(_('account type'), choices=USER_ACCOUNT_TYPE_CHOICES)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=255, unique=True)

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, username=None, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username, email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        if username:
            username = self.model.normalize_username(username)
            user = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)
        else:
            user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email=None, password=None, username=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, username=username, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, username=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, username=username, **extra_fields)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to override `createsuperuser` command.

To do this we need:

1. create path `our_project/our_app/management/commands`
2. Copy `createsuperuser.py` from `/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands` to the folder we created as the 1st step.
3. Edit file like below:

   ```
   for field_name in self.UserModel.REQUIRED_FIELDS:
       field = self.UserModel._meta.get_field(field_name)

       # Custom changes made from here to...

       str_to_show = None
       if hasattr(field, 'choices'):
           field_choices = field.choices
           list_of_str = []
           for each_choice in field_choices:
               choice_num = str(each_choice[0])
               choice_val = str(each_choice[1])
               list_of_str.append(choice_num + ' - ' + choice_val)
           str_to_show = ' (' + '; '.join(list_of_str) + ')'

       user_data[field_name] = options[field_name]
       while user_data[field_name] is None:
           if str_to_show:
               message = force_str('%s%s: ' % (
                   capfirst(field.verbose_name + str_to_show),
                   ' (%s.%s)' % (
                       field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
                       field.remote_field.field_name,
                   ) if field.remote_field else '',
               ))

           else:
               message = force_str('%s%s: ' % (
                   capfirst(field.verbose_name),
                   ' (%s.%s)' % (
                       field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
                       field.remote_field.field_name,
                   ) if field.remote_field else '',
               ))

           # ... to here

           input_value = self.get_input_data(field, message)
           user_data[field_name] = input_value
           fake_user_data[field_name] = input_value
   ```
4. In the `settings.py` put your app at the 1st position of `INSTALLED_APPS`, otherwise original `createsuperuser.py` executes when you use `createsuperuser` command in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the verbose name to include these options, as the verbose name is used for display purpose everywhere.

```
user_account_type = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Accout type (Options: 1 - organization, 2 - personal)", choices=USER_ACCOUNT_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

Of course you might want to wrap that in a method.

```
def account_type_verbose_name():
    choices = ["{} - {}".format(choice[0], choice[1]) for choice in USER_ACCOUNT_TYPE_CHOICES]
    return "Account Type (Options: {})".format(', '.join(choices))

    ....
    ....

user_account_type = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=account_type_verbose_name(), choices=USER_ACCOUNT_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

Comment: In this case the text `Accout type (Options: 1 - organization, 2 - personal)` appears both in terminal and in template. For template I have dropdown where is enough just to have `account type` label. Here is the problem - to have different texts for different places:)

Comment: It will be easier to change the label in the template rather than in the management command. You can take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py) and write your own command.